# Flash as3 - Send property name as variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, properties

I need to find a way in Flash AS3 to send a MovieClip property as a variable. I don't want to send the property value but the property itself. Here's an approach of what I want to achieve:

```
myFunction (mc:String, mcProperty:String, value:Number, iterations:int)
{
    for(var i:int = 1; i<=iterations; i++)
    {
        Tweener.addTween(this["mc" + i], { [mcProperty]:value, time:.8 } );
    }
}

myFunction ("myMovieClipName", "scaleX", 0, 8);
```

Does anyway have a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
myFunction (mc:String, mcProperty:String, value:Number, iterations:int)
{
    var prop:Object = {time:.8};
    prop[mcProperty] = value;

    for(var i:int = 1; i<=iterations; i++)
    {
        Tweener.addTween(this["mc" + i], prop );
    }
}

myFunction ("myMovieClipName", "scaleX", 0, 8);
```